# GNUStep Attempt to use SSL/TLS without support

Tags: openssl, gnustep

When I run my GNUStep tool, I get the following warning:

```
2011-01-30 18:21:49.382 GVPushNotificationServer[59326] Attempt to use SSL/TLS without support.
2011-01-30 18:21:49.382 GVPushNotificationServer[59326] Please reconfigure gnustep-base with GNU TLS.
```

How do I reconfigure gnustep-base with GNU TLS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on Old Nabble:

> 1. install tls on your machine ... you are probably using some sort of package manager and it may have a tls development package separate from the user package ... if so, you need to nstall the developer package so that the headers are available.
> 2. re-run configure for gnustep-base, check that it found your gnu tls library/headers, and rebuild gnustep-base

http://old.nabble.com/GNUStep-Attempt-to-use-SSL-TLS-without-support-td30803402.html

Comment: you can also mark your own answer as the solution to the question.